# MySQL выдает ошибку

Tags: php, mysql

Когда подключаюсь к MySQL через PHP выдает такую ошибку
`The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`
Вот код PHP:

```
<?php
  $mysqli =@new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'MySQL');
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to)

Comment: @new mysqli а не так ли надо? new mysqli собака зачем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так попробуйте

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "MySQL");
if(!$mysqli) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]